# Drop table fails with "Checksum doesn't match: corrupted data" exception on clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

So our unit tests for clickhouse started failing. Fails on simple SQL:

```cpp
::clickhouse::Client(client_options_).Execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.delme");
```

for client options I have host, default_database, user and password set.

the error:

```bash
[clickhouse error 40, DB::Exception: Checksum doesn't match: corrupted data. Reference: 8a58086e26544cb09217aa1bba09a1d9. Actual: 7c7a5cd56cac83a714e286dbbd46acb5. Size of compressed block: 20]
```

Errors on the server:

```bash
0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0xa38beba in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. ? @ 0x140ae996 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. DB::CompressedReadBufferBase::readCompressedData(unsigned long&, unsigned long&, bool) @ 0x140ad956 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. ? @ 0x140ace9f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. DB::NativeReader::read() @ 0x15cf19c4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. DB::TCPHandler::receiveData(bool) @ 0x15ccb990 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::TCPHandler::receivePacket() @ 0x15cc0a4f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. DB::TCPHandler::readDataNext() @ 0x15cc3c9f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. ? @ 0x15cceb68 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. DB::Context::initializeExternalTablesIfSet() @ 0x1474b5f6 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ? @ 0x14feb237 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. DB::executeQuery(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, bool, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum) @ 0x14fe9f0e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. DB::TCPHandler::runImpl() @ 0x15cb97ad in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. DB::TCPHandler::run() @ 0x15ccdd59 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection::start() @ 0x18a617b3 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::run() @ 0x18a62c2d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
16. Poco::PooledThread::run() @ 0x18c2d9c9 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
17. Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) @ 0x18c2b242 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
18. ? @ 0x7f4e74010609 in ?
19. __clone @ 0x7f4e73f35133 in ?
```

table does not exist, so no idea what data is corrupted.

clickhouse version: 22.8.2.11 using c++ client (https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-cpp)

I will try to recreate database and user, but wondering what led to these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment, so I'll write an answer.

Have you tried dropping the database test?

Maybe check in table system.parts, whether there are parts for this table. If yes, drop them.

Best regards,
Albert
albert1.cornelius+stackoverflow@gmail.com